# Disable adaptative refresh rate and set given refresh rate via adb

Tags: android, adb, refresh, frame, rate

I am using Honor Magic 4 Pro android device and I would like to disable adaptative refresh rate and set a given one.

This is what I have done:

`adb shell settings put system min_refresh_rate 90.0`

and then

`adb shell settings put system peak_refresh_rate 90.0`

I expected to set refresh rate to 90.0.

After checking it at the oscilloscope it does not work.

Please do you have some advice or additional knowledge on how to do it?